# How to subtract a month from a UNIX timestamp in PHP

Tags: php

How to subtract a month from a UNIX timestamp in PHP? I know this is a basic question but I cannot figure it out for the life of me. This is what I had but it doesn't work.

```
$Today = date();
$RegistrationStart->sub(new DateInterval('P1M'));
```

Comment: That's not a meaningful question. For example, what if there was a daylight saving's time change? Do you want the same time of day one calendar month ago? Do you mean in the current timezone? You need to specify your question very exactly.

Comment: what's your definition of a month anyways? 28/29/30/31 days? simply move the month value down 1 spot? e.g. `Mar 30` - 1 month is... what? Feb 30th, aka March 1st/2nd?

Comment: Doing dates properly isn't easy. I'd suggest using a date library like `Carbon` (https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon) to help you.  Then it just becomes `Carbon::now()->subMonth()`

Comment: How "*doesn't it work*"? What did you expect it to do that it's not doing or what did it do that you didn't expect? Please note you probably forgot to include the relevant part of your code that is `$RegistrationStart`, since you initialize `$Today` to the value of `date()`, which is a function that returns a string and expects a string argument, yet you provide it no arguments and don't even use it in your example. So that strange code, which doesn't tell us much of anything, coupled with the vague statement "*doesn't work*" definitely doesn't help us identify the real problem.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) parameters

```
date("n", 1438815650); //example unix in the second parameter, returns 8
date("F"); //returns August
date("m"); //returns 08
```

But like a lot of the people are saying in the comments, I have no idea if this is what you want. I'm assuming that you want '$Today' to contain the current month but you'll have to be more specific